# needed help for Mysql query to using Group By for matching first 10 characters in start of column value and group them under same name

Tags: php, mysql

I needed help for Mysql query to using Group By for matching first 10 characters in start of column values are like column, column1, column data, ... i want this same as show as group called column. I am trying following query but seems like its missing some records.

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM acx_projects 
WHERE type='projecttype' AND state='Live' 
GROUP BY Left(name, 10);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data from your table and the records you think are missing and the expected output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to extract first 10 characters in a field, then use a subquery to group by this field

```
select * from (
   SELECT 
      Left(name, 10) as FirtsChars, 
      id,  name 
   FROM acx_projects 
   where 
      type='projecttype' AND 
      state='Live'
) as Data 
Group by FirstChars;
```

Comment: thanks for answer, would it work if we have characters with space inside them.

Comment: I think so @Manu, comparison it's by character strings

Comment: There are no aggregating functions here, so what's GROUP BY for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, name, Left(name, 10) as sub FROM acx_projects wheretype='projecttype' AND state='Live' GROUP BY 3;
```